# How to setup Windows 7 to allow multiple users with password protected accounts to log in without having to enter a passwords on the login screen?

Tags: windows-7, login, password-protection, auto-login

I'd like to set up Windows 7 to do the following on startup:

- show a list of the users on the system
- if a user is clicked, they are logged in without having to enter their password (which shall be set and must be entered for remote access)
- if no user is clicked, after a given amount of time (say 10 seconds) a default user is logged in

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, you can't get there from here.  Either the account has a password or it doesn't.

I'm not sure if Windows 7 still allows for GINA replacement or if they have another method for pluggable authentication, but that might work. However, I have a feeling that it's still not possible to log a user on without the password being provided to windows.

Comment: so my best bet is omitting passwords, setting up dummy users for remote access, and either using autologin (requiring the non-default user to wait and re-login) or not (requiring all users that one click)? :-/

Comment: I see for Vista/7 it's using the [Credential Providers API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) instead of GINA...